# Remove blank values from combobox.

Tags: vb.net

I have database table RoosterRanks. 16 ID's - 16 titles. It looks like this

[image] ... Now i need to read the id-Titles to work with them. I need titles shown in combobox. But if i go like this

```
 sQL.Query("Select * from RoosterRanks")
 cbRank.DataSource = sQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
 cbRank.ValueMember = "Title"
 cbRank.SelectedIndex = -1
```

But this way in combobox i also have a Blank values Because the empty fileds are not NULL they are ""

I don't need result like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query. Theres others as well, but this will give you a few options...

```
 Select * FROM RoosterRanks 
 WHERE Len(Title) > 0
```

Or

```
 Select * FROM RoosterRanks
 WHERE Title <> ''
```

Or if you want to replace it with something...

```
 Select
   id,
   Case Title
     When NULL THEN 'Replacement'
     When '' THEN 'Replacement'
   End As Title
 FROM RoosterRanks
```

On another note you probably want your Title as the `DisplayMember` and id as your `ValueMember`

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer sir i just need to thing outside the box. It was logic solution also. How to pick up the id of selected item in combobox cbrank ? 

If i pick Stack how to pick its ID ?

Comment: Look into `SelectedValue` for example: cbRank.SelectedValue